# Possible to reassign a member entries to a member of a different member group?

Tags: members, delete

I created a member and member group specifically for the purpose of holding any deleted members data. Basically, when I delete a member, all its entries and comments would be reassigned to the aforementioned member.

However, when I tried deleting via EE Control Panel Admin, I noticed that the aforementioned member is not in the select dropdown of members to reassign to.

After a quick check, it seems to me that the choices in the select dropdown are the ones in the same member group as the member we are deleting.

Is there a way to circumvent this? If not, what is the purpose of this rule?

Answer (score 1):

You right, 
the system is choose members from user group: *"expressionengine/controllers/cp/members.php"* line 677 (EE 2.7.2).

```
$group_ids = $this->member_model->get_members_group_ids($damned);
```

In case if you will delete multi users from multi groups, it will show you users from multi groups.

Reason? As I think same group, same rights to do the same actions. Showing all groups is make more complicated requests or you will get too big list of members. For most sites this strategy is better.

You case is really exception. And tell the true - I can't find explanations for your requirements.

*update*

possible solution:

1. hack the core (where you can do this I indicate at beginning)
2. make alternative module for delete member
3. change member group before delete
4. if you want always assign to the same users - make ext. for hook [member_delete](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/member_model/index.html#member-delete) (it is just a couple lines).
5. create new user in the same group
6. send message to EllisLab and check if they decide to change this practice

Comment: I can think of some cases where assigning an entry to a member in a different group could be useful. In fact, I may need to do this myself soon. Are there any ways around this limitation?

Comment: just updated my post for solutions. Choose what is better for you